# Async function in Next.js onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**I'm trying to call an async function pushData() from a button onClick event, and i'm not sure what's wrong.**

```js
async function pushData() {
  alert("wee");
  console.log("pushing data");

  try {
    await query(`
    //SQL CODE
    `);

    console.log("Done");

  } catch (e) {

    console.error("wtf");
    console.log(e);

  }
}

import React from "react";

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
      </div>
      <button onClick={async () => await pushData()}>SQL BUTTON</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `alert('wee')` does work, but the `await` and `console.log()` don't do anything.

Comment: Which console log?

Comment: Everything looks right. What environment are you running it in?

Comment: @evolutionxbox none of them do anything

Comment: Even the first one `pushing data`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, that's weird.

Comment: Please may you edit the question to include a [mcve]. The current one does not behave as you describe.

Comment: Calling [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) will stop code execution until the user dismisses the alert dialog. You should see the logs in the console after you acknowledge the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

It looks like i was just tired and dumb. `onClick={pushData}` works fine after removing the `alert()`. For some reason the logs are logged into the DevTools console though.

Comment: Yes, that's what `console.log` does.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry about that. Guess i didn't have enough sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add async and await in the onClick attribute of the button. Just a simple pushData() function call will work.

Comment: They are indeed unnecessary but they shouldn't be causing problems

Comment: I know this sucks, but please wait to comment. Although you're correct, this is not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I only got this error when i tried this: "Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type."

I'm pretty sure i can't have `()` when i call the function in Next.js?

Comment: @LauriToikka don't call the function. Pass it in instead `onClick={pushData}`

Comment: @evolutionxbox that doesn't work either, only the `alert()` works.

Comment: @LauriToikka we can't help without an example that shows the issue. The one in the question will output the correct logs.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I understand, I had accidentally typed 'React' instead of 'Next.js' in the title, do you know if there's anything Next.js -specific I should consider?

Comment: Replace alert with console log? Alert blocks js until the box is dismissed.